# Type signature for function containing `runST`

Tags: haskell

I can write something like this:

```
import Control.Monad.ST (runST)

x :: (Monad m) => m a
x = undefined

f = runST x
```

And this will happily compile without a signature for `f`.

So I've tried something similar:

```
g :: (Monad m) => m a -> m a
g = undefined

h x = runST (g x)
```

Yet this doesn't compile without a signature. Which I don't mind too much, as `runST` is a rank-2 type, but I can't work out what signature to write for `h`.

*(Background)*

This is a simplified example of real code I'm writing. Firstly I've got a function that works in [MonadRef](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ref-tf) (e.g. ST or IO). It does a lot of manipulation on vectors. I'm creating a pure wrapper to this, but one needs to pass in the initial mutable vector, and it will produce a pure vector. Unlike the more general first mentioned function, the pure wrapper only works in ST.

Comment: Without a signature, the compiler can't see what you mean about the argument to `h`. It compiles if you add the signature `h :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a`

Comment: `runST` wants to choose `m` as `ST s` where `s` again is chosen by `runST`. In the latter case, `x` must already have type `ST s ...`, but is comes from outside, so someone else already chose `s` -- the argument to `runST`  is not general enough. One option could be letting `x :: forall s. ST s ...` but this is a polytype, and GHC does not infer those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type signature that you're looking for is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Test where

import Control.Monad.ST

g :: (Monad m) => m a -> m a
g = undefined

h :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
h x = runST (g x)
```

The `(forall s. ST s a)` ensures that `x` cannot decide what `s` will be and so `x` has to work for all `s`, so it cannot leak out `STRef` or similar out of the `ST` computation.

Comment: Thanks when I tried this something like this for my actual problem it didn't work out so I've either stuffed something up or my problem is not actually the same as this.

Comment: There might be something related to the fact that `s` is provided by a  type family in `MonadRef`. But I will have to see actual code that demonstrates your problem to see what it is.